# Two types of the Germain prime siblings

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Let $\ p\ $ and $\ q:=2\cdot p+1\ $ be primes — they are called Germain prime siblings. Such a pair belongs to the first type
$\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \frac{q^2-1}8\equiv\pm1\mod8,\ $ and to the second type
$\ \Leftarrow:\Rightarrow\ \frac{q^2-1}8\equiv\pm3\mod8.\ $

Do you know any results (in print or your own) about the frequency of the two types?

Comment: Perhaps you should add the **[reference-request]** tag, @WlodAA?

Comment: @ArnieBebita-Dris, thank you -- I've followed your suggestion.

Comment: I suggest you initially have a look at the [Wikipedia page on properties of Sophie Germain primes and safe primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes#Properties), and thereby review the references contained therein.

Comment: $(q^2-1)/8$ can also be even, e.g., $p=11$, $q=23$, $(q^2-1)/8=66\equiv2\bmod8$.